# Merge 2 queryset based on the on a condition

Tags: python, django-queryset

Background :- I am trying to merge 2 querysets from same model. 
Something like this. i.e. every 3rd counter they should be merged.

```
queryset = get_foo(person)  #First queryset
promoted_foo = get_promoted_foo()  #Second queryset
for (counter,(s,p)) in enumerate(itertools.izip(queryset,promoted_foo)):
    if counter%3==0:
        queryset.insert(counter,promoted_foo.pop())
if promoted_foo:
   queryset.extend(promoted_foo)
```

What is the most Pythonic way to do this ?
I know I can use list() on the quersets and then merge them. But that consumes a lot of memory. So what can be a alternative to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might define your own generator that lazily loads items from the querysets.

I haven't tested this but something like:

```
def everythird():
    queryset = get_foo(person)  #First queryset
    promoted_foo = get_promoted_foo()  #Second queryset
    for (counter,(s,p)) in enumerate(itertools.izip(queryset,promoted_foo)):
    if counter%3==0 and promoted_foo:
        yield promoted_foo
    elif queryset:
        yield queryset
```

Comment: I think `for row in qs: yield row` would be better

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate over queryset or promoted_foo if you're not going to use the values that are returned. You also shouldn't modify the container that you're iterating over from within the loop.

Another approach is:

```
# For a range with step size 3, from 0 until the length of the shortest container.
for idx in xrange(0, min(len(queryset), len(promoted_foo), 3):
   queryset.insert(idx, promoted_foo.pop())
if promoted_foo:
    queryset.extend(promoted_foo)
```

PS. That you are using insert() on queryset implies that it's a list already.